# onClick Jest / enzyme : Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, onclick, jestjs, enzyme

I am not being able to test onClick for the following code below. I keep getting the following error :

`Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

My component code looks like this:

```
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = INITIAL_STATE;
}

handleQuickFilter = (type) => {
  this.setState({
    quickFilterObj: {...this.state.quickFilterObj, [type]: {...this.state.quickFilterObj[type], checked: !this.state.quickFilterObj[type].checked}}
    }, () => {
      let filter = this.buildFilter();
      filter ? 
        linker.UniversalGrid('Counterparty.Loa.Enrollment', '', `{form_filter}=$filter=(${filter}),{grid_selectable}=1,{can_add}=1`) 
      :
        linker.UniversalGrid('Counterparty.Loa.Enrollment', '', `{form_filter}='',{grid_selectable}=1,{can_add}=1`)
  })
}

render () {
  return(
    <div className='enrollment-grid-wrapper'>   
      <div className='quick-filter-div'>
        <button className={this.state.quickFilterObj['New'] && this.state.quickFilterObj['New'].checked ? 'checked quick-filter' : 'unchecked quick-filter'} 
                id = 'testnew'
                onClick={() => {this.handleQuickFilter('New')}}
                >
            New {this.state.quickFilterObj['New'] && this.state.quickFilterObj['New'].count !== undefined ? `(${this.state.quickFilterObj['New'].count})` : null}
        </button>
        <button className={this.state.quickFilterObj['Sent'] && this.state.quickFilterObj['Sent'].checked ? 'checked quick-filter' : 'unchecked quick-filter'} 
                onClick={()=>{this.handleQuickFilter('Sent')}}
                >
            Sent {this.state.quickFilterObj['Sent'] && this.state.quickFilterObj['Sent'].count !== undefined ? `(${this.state.quickFilterObj['Sent'].count})` : null}
        </button>
  )
}
```

I have tried the following, using Jest / enzyme:

```
it("should HandlequickFilter with button click", () => { 
  wrapper.setProps({}); 
  wrapper.setState({quickFilterObj:"test"}); 
  wrapper.find('.quick-filter-div').at(0).simulate("click");
  expect(wrapper.state().quickFilterObj.New.checked).toEqual(true);
});
```

How could I make the following test to pass?

Comment: Are you using css modules? If so, you won't have a div with class `quick-filter-div`, but the class would be renamed to something with additional strings appended.

Comment: Yes. So how could i test onClick

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using css modules, your actual rendered DOM will not contain a `div` with class `quick-filter-div`. Instead, the class will be something like `quick-filter-div__012xyz`. Because of this, `wrapper.find('.quick-filter-div')` will return 0 nodes.

You can verify this by putting the following line in your test just after the `setState` line:

```
expect(wrapper.find('.quick-filter-div').exists()).toEqual(false)
```

But, it looks like what you want to test is the click of the `button` inside of your `div.quick-filter-div`. Isn't that correct? After all, the `onClick` handler is a prop for the `button` rather than the `div`.

And, because your `button` has been given an id, you can do:

```
it("should HandlequickFilter with button click", () => { 
  wrapper.setProps({}); 
  wrapper.setState({quickFilterObj:"test"}); 
  const button = wrapper.find('button#testnew') // find button based on id selector
  expect(button.exists()).toEqual(true)         // make sure button is found
  button.simulate("click");                     // simulate click
  expect(wrapper.state().quickFilterObj.New.checked).toEqual(true);
});
```

If you didn't give an id to your button, but you knew that the button click you wanted to test was the first button (rather than the second one), then you could try:

```
it("should HandlequickFilter with button click", () => { 
  wrapper.setProps({}); 
  wrapper.setState({quickFilterObj:"test"}); 
  const buttons = wrapper.find('button')        // find all buttons
  expect(buttons).toHaveLength(2)               // make sure you found 2 buttons
  const button = buttons.at(0)                  // get the first button
  button.simulate("click");                     // simulate click
  expect(wrapper.state().quickFilterObj.New.checked).toEqual(true);
});
```

Comment: Both of them are not working . For the first answer i get False instead of true. The second one is eve more complicated -  i get false as well and expect : showing everything under render

Comment: @user9191 Are you using Enzyme's `render` or `shallow`? This works if you use `shallow`. Try to set `wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent />)` instead of `render`

Comment: using shallow - the way you described above

Comment: I added more information on my question that might help find the problem. please take a look

Comment: @user9191 Can you also post your jest/enzyme code? Most importantly, how do you declare and assign `wrapper`?

Comment: @user9191 By the way, in your `setState` line of your component code, you have `quickFilterObj: {...this.state.quickFilterObj, [type]` - is that a typo? Do you mean to have that comma there, or is it supposed to be `quickFilterObj: {...this.state.quickFilterObj[type]:` ?

Comment: it is supposed to have a comma there -

Comment: What is causing the problem ?

Comment: Have you tried using `shallow` instead of `render`? Can you post your jest/enzyme code?

Comment: I use shallow instead of render

Comment: @user9191 What was the result?

Comment: same result as before.doesnt pass

Comment: Looking at your LOA code, I see that there are more buttons in your component than just 2. So, in my second test example above, you should try
`expect(buttons).toHaveLength(9)` followed by `const button = buttons.at(2)` Also, I can't run your LOA tests in the code sandbox because `Could not find module in path: '../../Utils/UniversalLinker' relative to '/src/components/LOA/LOA.js'`

Comment: import * as linker from '../../Utils/UniversalLinker'; ??

Comment: Also i made the adjustment to 9 and 2 - still failing

Comment: Yea i have to fix my setState in order to pass. I will loonk into it later. could you please edit the previous commment -  dont  want sandbox link here.. thanks for the help

Comment: You're welcome. I'm going to delete the forked sandbox and remove the comment. I hope that answer has helped you. If so, please [consider accepting my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Happy coding!

Comment: answer fixed -  take a look

Answer (score 0):

Must add a return new Promise in your jest.fn function

```
//mocking functions
getSelectedLOAs  = jest.fn( () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
resolve()
})
});


it("should test click event NEW  method", () => {
wrapper.setProps({
});
wrapper.find('COMPONENT').setState({ 
  quickFilterObj:{
    New: {
      checked: true
    },
    Sent: {
      checked: true
    },

   }, } );
wrapper.update();
wrapper.find('#New-testclick').simulate("click");
wrapper.find('#Sent-testclick').simulate("click");
```